# reset name and the value of the combobox item

Tags: javascript, jquery

on certain event I want to change combobox selection to be reset to it's default state, and I'm using

```
$("select#Name").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

try with

```
$("select#Name").val(0);
$("select#Name").val('0');
$("select#Name").val('');
$("select#Name").val(0).change();
```

this successfully reset the selected value but previous selection text remains inside combo, how to reset this too without explicitly target text property of this element.

Is there one expression to reset name and the value?

Comment: have you tried instead of using 0, use 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$("select#Name").val($("select#Name option:first").val());
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $("select#Name").val($("select#Name option:first").val()); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='Name'>
    <option value='val_1'>Text 1</option>
    <option value='val_2'>Text 2</option>
    <option value='val_3'>Text 3</option>
    <option value='val_4'>Text 4</option>
</select>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: It's work for me, please check the example in my updated answer.